# spinner cant show data from sd card

Tags: android, spinner

This is code to add data into spinner. 
first i read file name from sd card then adding it to spinner. but it cant work. it only display first file name.

```
   File yourDir = new File(catagoryFilePath);
        for (File f : yourDir.listFiles()) {
            if (f.isFile()) {

                myCatagoryFilename = f.getName();

            }

            try {
                String categoryFileName[] = myCatagoryFilename.split("@");
                for(int i = 0; i<categoryFileName.length; i++){
                    String catagoryData = categoryFileName[i];
                    if (catagoryData.contains("-")) {
                        String data[] = catagoryData.split("-");
                        String lang = data[0];
                        String cat = data[1];
                    }
                }

                String catagoryName = categoryFileName[2];


            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            catagory = new ArrayList<String>();
            catagory.add(myfileName);
        }
```

this is how i set spinner adepter.

```
catagoryAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner, catagory);
        catagoryAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner);
        mySpinnerCatagoryList.setAdapter(catagoryAdapter);
```

Comment: _catagory_ list size is  **0**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not adding the name in the `catagory` list. make these changes where the `loop` is running so it will add all the filenames.

```
catagory = new ArrayList<String>();

File yourDir = new File(catagoryFilePath);
            for (File f : yourDir.listFiles()) {
                if (f.isFile()) {

                    myCatagoryFilename = f.getName();

                catagory.add(myfileName);//myCatagoryFileName

                }

                try {
                    String categoryFileName[] = myCatagoryFilename.split("@");
                    for(int i = 0; i<categoryFileName.length; i++){
                        String catagoryData = categoryFileName[i];
                        if (catagoryData.contains("-")) {
                            String data[] = catagoryData.split("-");
                            String lang = data[0];
                            String cat = data[1];
                        }
                    }

                    String catagoryName = categoryFileName[2];


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are resetting the variable `catagory` with each iteration of the loop. Move this line out of your `for` loop:

```
catagory = new ArrayList<String>(); // move this line up.
for (File f : yourDir.listFiles()) {
  // the rest
  catagory.add(myfileName);
}
```